# Passing variable from urls.py to html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I set django-built-in messages to pass some info from my views.py file to html file directly.

I'm using directly `messages.info(request, "User credentials are updated.")` to send messages.

As you see below, it works fine.

[image]

Right now, I am planning to pass variables from urls.py to HTML directly.

Something like below:

```
path('password_change_done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name="account/dashboard.html"), **{'messages': 'User credentials are updated.'}**, name='password_change_done')
```

When I search for it, I see that I can send a dictionary but it doesn't work for me.
I tried to stick the same format(messages dictionary) where HTML expects.

```
**{'messages': 'User credentials are updated.'}**
```

Part of my urls.py file:

```
# Password change

# 1 ) Submit password change form

path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name="account/password/password-change-form.html"), name='password_change'),

# 2 ) Success message stating that password is changed

path('password_change_done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name="account/dashboard.html"), **{'message': 'User credentials are updated.'}**, name='password_change_done'),
```

Part of my dashboard.html file:

```
<!-- Django's built-in message template part -->

{% for message in messages %}

    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS %}

        <h6 id="message-timer" class="alert alert-success text-center"> <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; {{ message }} </h6>

    {% endif %}

    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}

        <h6 id="message-timer" class="alert alert-danger text-center"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; {{ message }} </h6>

    {% endif %}

    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.INFO %}

    <h6 id="message-timer" class="alert alert-info text-center"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; {{ message }} </h6>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first the `messages` is only acting as a keyword argument since you're passing it through [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) function, they are not like messages framework, they are just only kwargs to show in the templates unlike messages which appear only one time and disappear when the page is refreshed.

So, overall you should use the way it is working, passing it as the kwargs is not the recommended way since they'd appear all the time.

You can confirm this by printing its value in the template as:

```html
<!-- Django's built-in message template part -->

{% for message in messages %}

    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS %}

        <h6 id="message-timer" class="alert alert-success text-center"> <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; {{ message }} </h6>

    {% endif %}

    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}

        <h6 id="message-timer" class="alert alert-danger text-center"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; {{ message }} </h6>

    {% endif %}

    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.INFO %}

    <h6 id="message-timer" class="alert alert-info text-center"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; {{ message }} </h6>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

<h1>Your message: {{messages}}</h1>  {% comment %} It is acting as a kwarg and would appear all the time and can't be used as a message. {% endcomment %}
```